# Union an array of objects in rego

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

How do I union an array of objects into one object in `rego`?

I know how to union two objects, but how do I loop through an array of objects?

This sample works, but it is (obvious) not scalable ;)

```
a := [{"test1": "123"}, {"test2": "456"}, {"test3": "789", "test4": "012"}]

b := {
        "my-property": object.union(object.union(a[0], a[1]), a[2])
     }
```

**Expected output:**

```json
{
  "test1": "123", 
  "test2": "456",
  "test3": "789",
  "test4": "012"
}
```

Thanks!
Casper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; assuming the object keys are unique (like in your example), you can simply use a [comprehension](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#comprehensions):

```
b := {k: v | 
    some i, k
    v := a[i][k]
}
```

Since the variable `i` is only used once, you can replace it with `_` to avoid having to come up with a name:

```
b := {k: v | 
    some k
    v := a[_][k]
}
```

If the object keys are not unique then it's slightly more complicated because you need to decide how to resolve conflicts when two objects contain the same key with different values. How you decide to resolve conflicts will depend on the use case. One way to resolve them is to just group values by their keys. For example:

```
# the 'test2' key appears in more than one object with a different value
a := [{"test1": "123"}, {"test2": "456"}, {"test3": "789", "test2": "012"}]
```

To group the values by keys, you can write a nested comprehension:

```
{k: vs |
    # for each key 'k'
    some k
    conflicting[_][k]

    # find all values for key 'k' and group as a set
    vs := {v | v := conflicting[_][k]}
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "test1": [
        "123"
    ],
    "test2": [
         "012",
         "456"
    ],
    "test3": [
         "789"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I did try with object comprehension but the part that I was missing was the `k: v `-part. Again, thank you!